# Magento 2 unable to save category custom attribute value

Tags: magento2, category, attributes, magento2.3.1

I have created below modules to create custom category attributes, but values are not getting saved from admin . below is my module code please with what i am missing

1: Yereone/NewCategoryAttribute/Setup/InstallData.php

```
namespace Yereone\CustomCategoryAttribute\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;


class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Installs data for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'custom_category_attr',
            [
                'type'         => 'varchar',
                'label'        => 'Yereone Custom Category Attribute',
                'input'        => 'text',
                'sort_order'   => '',
                'source'       => '',
                'global'       => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'visible'      => true,
                'required'     => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default'      => null,
                'group'        => '',
                'backend'      => ''
            ]
        );

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

2: Yereone/NewCategoryAttribute/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="yereone_settings">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Yereone</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="custom_category_attr">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Yereone Custom Category Attribute</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">150</item>
                    <item name="scopeLabel" xsi:type="string">[STORE VIEW]</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't you need to define  `scopeLabel` (`<item name="scopeLabel" xsi:type="string">[STORE VIEW]</item>`)  at here.

> ```
> <fieldset name="content" sortOrder="100">
>     <settings>
>         <collapsible>true</collapsible>
>         <label translate="true">Yereone</label>
>     </settings>
>      <field name="custom_category_attr" sortOrder="30" formElement="input">
>         <settings>
>             <dataType>string</dataType>
>             <label translate="true">Yereone Custom Category Attribute</label>
>         </settings>
>     </field>
> </fieldset>
> ```

Comment: still it does not work

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like

view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="test">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">500</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Test</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Setup/InstallData.php

```
namespace Xigen\Category\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'test',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Test',
                'input' => 'text',
                'sort_order' => 500,
                'source' => '',
                'global' => 1,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => null,
                'group' => 'General Information',
                'backend' => ''
            ]
        );
    }
}
```